# Should Brain-Flak Birthday challenges be tagged Brain-Flak?

Tags: discussion, tags

As you may or may not have noticed, we are doing a series of [Brain-Flak Birthday challenges](https://hackmd.io/KwRgnARiAcCGAsBaaEBMAGR8DG8Cmis0AZsVhPLOtsWAOzQAmIQA?view) to celebrate Brain-Flak's first birthday.

Some questions in this series are only tangentially related to brain-flak by the [balanced-string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/balanced-string) aspect (and that's fine they're still interesting challenges). There has been a difference in opinion on whether these challenges should be marked with [brain-flak](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brain-flak) among us flakkers, so I thought I would ask the meta.

Is it useful to mark all BFBCs with the [brain-flak](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brain-flak) tag? Should we do so?

Answer (score 3):

## Yes

Let's take a look at the tag wiki.

```
This challenge is related to the Brain-flak esoteric language and 
languages based on Brain-Flak. 
Note that challenges that require the answers to be in a specific language are generally discouraged
```

I feel in some sense you may have answered your own question. These challenges are related to Brain-Flak. While it may be somewhat tangential of a relationship it still is beneficial. Tags serve to categorize questions and help users locate questions they find interesting. It is likely that Brain-Flak aficionados (who watch this tag) may find these questions interesting, therefore I do believe it is useful to have them categorized (and if they don't find it interesting they can always continue to scroll past it).

Comment: Hehe `Brian-Flak` sounds like a great spin-off language ;)

Comment: @BetaDecay Maybe a cross between [Brian & Chuck](https://github.com/m-ender/brian-chuck) and Brain-Flak.